# show error bar in multi line plot using matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I've created a multi line plot using marplot lib, and now I want to show the min-max value for each parameter on X-axis. My code is below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': ['D=0','D=2','D=5','D=X'],
    'Latency': [74.92, 75.32, 79.64, 100],
    'Delay': [18.2,80,82,84]
   })

  plt.plot( 'Time', 'Latency', data=df, marker='s', color='black', markersize=4,     linewidth=1, linestyle='--')
  plt.plot( 'Time', 'Delay', data=df, marker='o', color='black',  markersize=4, linewidth=1,linestyle='-')

   plt.legend()
   plt.xlabel("Time")
   plt.ylabel("Average Score (%)")
   plt.ylim(0, 100)
   plt.xlim('D=0','D=X')
   plt.savefig('Fig2.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
   plt.show()
```

The interval min-max that I want to add is:

```
Latency: 
D=0 => {73.3, 76}
D=2 => {73.3, 80}
D=5 => {75, 83.3}
D=X => {100}
Delay:
D=0 => {0, 50}
D=2 => {50, 100}
D=5 => {68, 90}
D=X => {75, 90}
```

Thanks so much in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First put the error values in lists:

```
latency_lower_err = [73.3, 73.3, 75, 100]
latency_upper_err = [76, 80, 83.3, 100]
```

Then subtract the data points from these values, because `matplotlib` needs the distance (in absolute units) from the error limit to the corresponding data point:

```
latency_lower_err = (latency_lower_err - df['Latency']).abs() 
latency_upper_err = (latency_upper_err - df['Latency']).abs()
```

Put the resulting values in a list, where the first element is the lower errors, and the second element is the upper errors:

```
yerr = [latency_lower_err, latency_upper_err]
```

Then change the call from `plt.plot` to `plt.errorbar`, adding the `yerr` argument:

```
plt.errorbar('Time', 'Latency', data=df, yerr=yerr, capsize=5, ... )
```

The remaining arguments are the same you previously used for `plt.plot`.

Result:

[image]

Adapt the same logic for `Delay` in order to get the errors for that variable, too.

Answer (score 2):

`plt.errorbar()` draws lineplots with error bars. It's parameters are quite similar to `plt.plot()`. The xlims need to be a bit wider to avoid the error bars being cut by the plot borders.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': ['D=0', 'D=2', 'D=5', 'D=X'],
                   'Latency': [74.92, 75.32, 79.64, 100],
                   'Delay': [18.2, 80, 82, 84]})
latency_min_max = np.array([(73.3, 76), (73.3, 80), (75, 83.3), (100, 100)]).T
latency_err = np.abs(latency_min_max - df['Latency'].to_numpy())
delay_min_max = np.array([(0, 50), (50, 100), (68, 90), (75, 90)]).T
delay_err = np.abs(delay_min_max - df['Delay'].to_numpy())

plt.errorbar('Time', 'Latency', yerr=latency_err, data=df, marker='s', capsize=2,
             color='black', markersize=4, linewidth=1, linestyle='--')
plt.errorbar('Time', 'Delay', yerr=delay_err, data=df,
             marker='o', capsize=4, color='black', markersize=4, linewidth=1, linestyle='-')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("Average Score (%)")
plt.ylim(0, 100)
plt.xlim(-0.2, 3.2)
plt.savefig('Fig2.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

An alternative is to use `plt.fill_between` to create error bands:

```py
plt.fill_between(df['Time'], latency_min_max[0, :], latency_min_max[1, :], color='red', alpha=0.2, label='Latency error')
plt.fill_between(df['Time'], delay_min_max[0, :], delay_min_max[1, :], color='blue', alpha=0.2, label='Delay error')
```

[image: plot with errorbands]

Answer (score 1):

You should use `plt.errorbar` instead of `plt.plot`, then assign the absolute value of the difference between the data points and the lower/upper limits as the lower/upper error values (numpy has convenient vectorization to do this). To avoid the caps of the error bars overlapping and which could be confusing, I would suggest using different colors and updating the legend.

From a presentation perspective, it would probably look nicer to have some whitespace around the axes so the data doesn't look cut off - you can set the `plt.xlim` and `plt.ylim` accordingly. Credit to @JohanC for doing this first.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': ['D=0','D=2','D=5','D=X'],
    'Latency': [74.92, 75.32, 79.64, 100],
    'Delay': [18.2,80,82,84]
   })

latency_limits = np.array([[73.3,73.3,75,100],[76,80,83.3,100]])
delay_limits = np.array([[0,50,68,75],[50,100,90,90]])

latency_errors = abs(df.Latency.values - latency_limits)
delay_errors = abs(df.Delay.values - delay_limits)

yerr = np.array([[1,1,1,1],[5,5,5,5]])

fig = plt.figure()
Latency = plt.errorbar(
  x=df.Time, 
  y=df.Latency, 
  yerr=latency_errors, 
  capsize=4,
  marker='s', 
  color='red', 
  markersize=4, 
  linewidth=1, 
  linestyle='--')

Delay = plt.errorbar(
  x=df.Time, 
  y=df.Delay, 
  yerr=delay_errors,
  capsize=4,
  marker='o', 
  color='blue',  
  markersize=4, 
  linewidth=1,
  linestyle='-')

plt.legend((Latency, Delay),("Latency","Delay"))
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("Average Score (%)")
## widen both limits to give some whitespace to the plot
plt.ylim(-5, 105)
plt.xlim(-0.2, 3.2)
# plt.savefig('Fig2.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
plt.margins(5,5)
plt.show()
```

[image]